# I have a report on Visual studio, now the ABC column of reports is unsorted. How can I sort the data in ABC column? the report is .rdl in VS 12

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, report

```
ABC        379103   239     191         470            
DEF        22556884 45632   454878745   4777
```

I need to sort the column (ABC) data (descending order) with its corresponding other few columns. (DEF) is another column. They are columns of my report, I have written in horizontal way.

Report picks data from csv files, using ssrs. working on Visual studio.

```
eee     379103          445562.61        ZTE    678830    5012755.11     
eee      239             18762.66         ZTE    44        5455.63  
ddd      1215            3335.91          ZTE    350       30068.25  
3e4      3318            66303.90         ZTE    43        50.91
```

I need to sort second column.

Second column data must be sorted in decreasing order and then other columns will be arranged accordingly with respect to it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort the columns independently? Or do you mean you want to sort the rows by the data in ABC column?

Comment: I want to sort rows , with other corresponding values of other columns. That means ABC should be like ABC 191  239 470 379103  with DEF sorted accordingly-- DEF  45487845  45632  4777 22556884 and other columns also get sorted like this. I don't want to sort independently.